# Java undirected Graph distance computation

Tags: java

I am having the following matrix stored in 2d int array result[][]:

```
0 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0
```

I am trying to compute if there are any nodes that are connected with distance of 2 (there is 1 node in between them and no direct connection)

So far I have the following code:
Size is the size of the matrix (n * n) and dis is the distance I am looking for.

```
for(int row = 0; row < size; row++){
    for(int column = 0; column < size; column++){
        if(dis == 2){
            if((result[row][column] == dis-1 && result[column][column+1] == 1  && result[row][column+1] == 0)){
                if(row != column+1){
                    result[row][column+dis-1] = dis;
                    result[column+dis-1][row] = dis;
                }
            }
        }
      }
     }
```

However, the code does not always work and is not universal if I try to change the distance to 3 or 4 for example.

Comment: I would recommend that you compute the set of numbers that are one jump from each other, and the set of nodes that are two jumps from each other, then return the set from two jump that are not in one jump. For this I would recommend Floyd-Warshall

Comment: You're storing the result in the original array? So that we can understand what you're trying to do, what is the outcome you're expecting with the specified input?

Comment: Floyd-Warshall is $O(n^3)$ and finds shortest distance between all points in a connected graph. See [here](en.wikipedia.org/Floyd_Warshall_Algorithm)